# Yarn Container wrong hostname when contacting ResourceManager

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm trying to write a simple query in Hive (just an INSERT) but I'm having issues with how MapReduce jobs are being provisioned. Containers are getting allocated correctly, but my jobs never run.

[image]

It seems that they're contacting the ResourceManager incorrectly. I have verified (via JPS) that my ResourceManager is indeed running, and is running on hostname `hadoop1.personal` which all servers have a reference to in /etc/hosts. The issue looks like this:

```
2016-09-27 09:41:55,223 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2016-09-27 09:41:55,224 INFO [Socket Reader #1 for port 45744] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 45744
2016-09-27 09:41:55,230 INFO [IPC Server Responder] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2016-09-27 09:41:55,230 INFO [IPC Server listener on 45744] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 45744: starting
2016-09-27 09:41:55,299 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor: nodeBlacklistingEnabled:true
2016-09-27 09:41:55,300 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor: maxTaskFailuresPerNode is 3
2016-09-27 09:41:55,300 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor: blacklistDisablePercent is 33
2016-09-27 09:41:55,375 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8030
2016-09-27 09:41:56,414 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-09-27 09:41:57,415 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-09-27 09:41:58,415 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-09-27 09:41:59,416 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-09-27 09:42:00,417 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

And of course it does go on for some time before eventually dying.
Now, I know that my configurations are getting picked up in some sense. Earlier in the logs, the containers say `2016-09-27 09:41:52,783 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.jobhistory.JobHistoryUtils: Default file system [hdfs://hadoop1.personal:8020]` which is the correct `NameNode` to be using.

Additionally, if I go to the NodeManager configuration (i.e. `http://hadoop2.personal:8042/conf`) then I can see that:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>hadoop1.personal</value>
  <source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
  <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8030</value>
  <source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>
```

So the `NodeManager` appears to know exactly where it needs to be at.

This seems incredibly strange to me: The NodeManager and ResourceManagers are talking together just fine, but containers are contacting the wrong scheduler. How do I control the address the containers are contacting for scheduling?

As a sidenote, I have tested this both with and without IPv6 enabled as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29690094/1454178). No effect.